# How can I find out what debugger is attached to w3p.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm trying to setup debugging on a class ASP project in VS 2010, and in doing that am trying to attach it's debugger to w3p.exe.  I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and IIS 7.5. I've used this method successfully a few times before on another machine.

However, I'm finding that this time I am unable to attach the debugger. It's saying:

```
Unable to attach to the process. A debugger is already attached.
```

But I can't figure out what it might be. How can I determine this? Or could it be something else? I've rebooted my PC and can't yet see signs of anything running which looks like a debugger.

### Setup

In case it helps, here's the steps I used to setup the environment, which I documented from my previous successful attempts:

- Created new empty Visual Basic .NET Web (Best to create in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\, otherwise you will have security/ACL issues when loading the site).
- Copied the contents of site folder to project folder.
- In solution explorer, selected to show all files not in project. Selected all files and right click and select: "include in project".
- Under project properties -> Web -> Set to use IIS and start with URL http://mysite.local
- In hosts file pointed mysite.local to 127.0.0.1
- In IIS setup new website pointing to the files with a host header of mysite.local
- Go to application pools, ensured mysite.local was set to classic mode. No managed code.
- Under ASP -> Enable Parent paths and make sure server-side debugging is enabled
- Under error pages, make sure full details are shown.

Debugging in Visual Studio 2010

- Run VS 2010 as Administrator
- In your project, use Ctrl+F5 to run without debugging
- Now, in the menu go to Debug -> Attach to Process **-- This is where I fail**
- Tick show processes from all users AND show processes in all sessions
- Make sure it is set to automatically determine type of code to debug
- Look through the w3p.exe processes in the list, and based on the IIS POOL\site name, pick the right process.
- Set your breakpoints and refresh -- debug as normal.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

Are you having some Debug Diagnostics Tool running on your machine. Sometimes back i had the same problem the Debug Diagnostics Tool was debugging my w3p process.

Comment: I did read that - but I can't find any sign of it. Is it something that comes with Windows, or does it need to be installed? I've never installed that.

Comment: OK yep. I don't think I have this, since it's downloadable.